# Elder Scrolls: What happened to the dragon statue left when Martin Septim's Dragon petrified?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion, the-elder-scrolls-series

Is it now a temple or something else in 4E of Skyrim?

Answer (score 5):

The [Wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Temple_of_the_One) has no information on it, so it's safe to say there is no lore. There is no particular reason why anyone would remove it, so it likely still stands in timespan of TESV.

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be any more info about this. It might've been like that forever, as it's mentioned to be a memorial of Martin. There's seems to be nothing else about this. That's all.